# Finding oldest record, newest record, and total records for a specific user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I have a database that contains various users who complete tasks. I want to find, per user:

- the date of the oldest task solved
- the date of the most recent task solved
- the total tasks solved

```
    user  | resolved date | task 
    -------------------------------------
    jim   | 20190103      | a 
    jim   | 20160117      | b
    james | 20191001      | c
    holly | 20190203      | d
    john  | 20180301      | e 
    john  | 20190401      | f
    holly | 20180101      | g
    james | 20191212      | h 
    james | 20191107      | i
```

I want to see a result like below:

```
user  | oldestdate | mostrecentdate | totaltasks
------------------------------------------------
jim   | 2016117    | 20190103       | 2     
james | 20191001   | 20191212       | 3 
holly | 20180101   | 20190203       | 2 
john  | 20180301   | 20190401       | 2
```

In addition how would I limit it to count for only tasks totalling > 50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select 
    user,
    min(resolved_date) oldest_date,
    max(resolved_date) most_recent_date,
    count(*) total_tasks
from mytable
group by user
```

Comment: how would i limit it to count for only tasks totaling > 50?

Comment: @sqlhelpneed: use a `having` clause: `select ... from mytable
group by user having count(*) > 50`.

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate your rows using the functions `min`, `max`, `count` along with a `group by` clause:

```
select [user]
    , min([resolved date]) oldestdate
    , max([resolved date]) mostrecentdate
    , count(*) totaltasks
from MyTable
group by [user];
```

To answer you additional question, to show results when the task total is greater than 50 use the `having` clause e.g.

```
select [user]
    , min([resolved date]) oldestdate
    , max([resolved date]) mostrecentdate
    , count(*) totaltasks
from MyTable
group by [user]
having count(*) > 50;
```

Comment: how would i limit it to count for only tasks totaling > 50?